# How to avoid undesired fields in response (scrapy)

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

Hi and thanks in advance:

When I run scrapy I put the items in a .json but instead of the items I want I get some garbage:

[download latency,download tieout, depth and download slot are the not desired ones](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAJdO.png)

```
 1 import scrapy
 2
 3 class LibresSpider(scrapy.Spider):
 4     name = 'libres'
 5     allowed_domains = ['www.todostuslibros.com']
 6     start_urls = ['https://www.todostuslibros.com/mas_vendidos/']
 7
 8     def parse(self, response):
 9         for tfg in response.css('li.row-fluid'):
10             doc={}
11             data = tfg.css('book-basics')
12             doc['titulo'] = tfg.css('h2 a::text').extract_first()
13             doc['url'] = response.urljoin(tfg.css('h2 a::attr(href)').extract_first())
14
15             yield scrapy.Request(doc['url'], callback=self.parse_detail, meta=doc)
16
17         next = response.css('a.next::attr(href)').extract_first()
18         if next is not None:
19            next_page = response.urljoin(next)
20            yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
21
22     def parse_detail(self, response):
23
24         detail = response.meta
25         detail['page_count'] = ' '.join(response.css('dd.page.count::text').extract())
26         detail['keywords'] = ' '.join(response.css('div.descripcio a::text').extract())
27
28         yield detail
```

I know that those undesired data came with the response (line 26) but I would like to know how to avoid that data which ends in my json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use a more explicit title to help other people who may have the same concerns; "garbage" is a very vague word.

You can have more information about the `meta` attribute in Scrapy documentation [here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.meta)

> A dict that contains arbitrary metadata for this request.  This dict
>   is empty for new Requests, and is usually populated by different
>   Scrapy components (extensions, middlewares, etc).  So the data
>   contained in this dict depends on the extensions you have enabled.

If you want to avoid having all these informations populated by Scrapy in your json, you can do as follow:

```
def parse(self, response):
  for tfg in response.css('li.row-fluid'):
    doc={}
    data = tfg.css('book-basics')
    doc['titulo'] = tfg.css('h2 a::text').extract_first()
    doc['url'] = response.urljoin(tfg.css('h2 a::attr(href)').extract_first())

    request = scrapy.Request(doc['url'], callback=self.parse_detail)
    request.meta['detail'] = doc
    yield request

  next = response.css('a.next::attr(href)').extract_first()
  if next is not None:
    next_page = response.urljoin(next)
    yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)

def parse_detail(self, response):
  detail = response.meta['detail']
  detail['page_count'] = ' '.join(response.css('dd.page.count::text').extract())
  detail['keywords'] = ' '.join(response.css('div.descripcio a::text').extract())
  yield detail
```